# How to get admin token in magento 2.1.8?

Tags: c#, .net, magento

I'm trying to get an admin token from Magento version 2.1.8 in c# using well-known code that works for all except me. Could not understand where is the problem.
In response I get:

```
ErrorException = null, Content= "{\" message \ ": \" Request does not match any path. \ ", \" trace \ ": null}"
```

```
public Magento(string magentoUrl)
    {
        //Relative URL needs to be Specified
        var endpoint = "/rest/V1/integration/admin/token";

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        var _restClient = new RestClient(magentoUrl);
        var request = new RestRequest(endpoint, Method.POST);

        //Initialize Credentials Property
        var userRequest = new Credentials { username = "reewrew", password = "rwerwerw" };
        var inputJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userRequest);

        //Request Header
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        //Request Body
        request.AddParameter("application/json", inputJson, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        var response = _restClient.Execute(request);

        var token = response.Content;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I use HTTP instead of HTTPS in URL.